# Can constraints be enforced on public data types?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code :

```
-- A CharBox is a rectangular matrix of characters
data CharBox = CharBox [String]
    deriving Show

-- Build a CharBox, ensuring the contents are rectangular
mkCharBox :: [String] -> CharBox
mkCharBox [] = CharBox []
mkCharBox xxs@(x:xs) =  if (all (\s -> (length s) == length x) xs)
                        then CharBox xxs
                        else error "CharBox must be a rectangle."
```

The `[[Char]]` must be rectangular (i.e. all sub-lists must have the same length) for many functions in the module to work properly. Inside the module I'm always using the `mkCharBox` "constructor" so I don't have to enforce this constraint all the time.

Initially I wanted my module declaration to look like this :

```
module CharBox (
    CharBox, -- No (CharBox) because it doesn't enforce rectangularity
    mkCharBox
) where
```

But like that, users of my module cannot pattern match on `CharBox`. In another module I do

```
findWiresRight :: CharBox -> [Int]
findWiresRight (CharBox xs) = elemIndices '-' (map last xs)
```

And ghci complains: `Not in scope: data constructor 'CharBox'`

**Is it possible to enforce my constraint that `CharBox`es contain only rectangular arrays, while still allowing pattern matching ?** (Also if this is not possible, I'd be interested in knowing the technical reason why. I find there's usually a lot to learn in Haskell when exploring such restrictions)

Comment: [View patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) might be one of the solutions, but I'd recommend just putting all the functions against `CharBox` in its module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible in vanilla Haskell to both hide the constructors and support pattern matching.

The usual approaches to address this are:

- [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns), essentially, export the pattern matching functions.

or:

- move the invariant into the type system via [size types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-0.0.2.0/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html).

Comment: See [Record syntax: validate contents in constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802590/record-syntax-validate-contents-in-constructor?lq=1) for using view patterns to hide the constructors and still support pattern matching on a public data type

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to add an extract function to the module:

```
extract :: CharBox -> [String]
extract (CharBox xs) = xs
```

and then use it instead of pattern matching:

```
findWiresRight :: CharBox -> [Int]
findWiresRight c = elemIndices '-' $ map last $ extract c
```