# Record syntax: validate contents in constructor

Tags: haskell

I have a record with 12 values. There are a few combinations of values that are not valid, so I would like the constructor to check this. I only know how to make constructors that take a list of arguments, but that's not very pretty with 12 values. Thus, I would like to use record syntax when using the value after having constructed it.

How do I enforce constraints in the constructor(s) and still use record syntax?

Comment: One way would be to use "blueprints". Make the blueprint's constructor open and unvalidated, and actual data constructor hidden behind a `Blueprint -> ActualData` function.

Comment: well you can choose **not** to publish the constructor from your module and use a *smart-constructor* (a function) that checks your conditions and publish it

Comment: @Carsten but that function won't use the record syntax, which I suppose was the main point here.

Comment: depending on the circumstances there might be ways to do this using the strictly in the type-system but it's probably rather complicated and of course you would have to make this more concrete

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz in this case I think I don't understand the question at all...

Comment: @Carsten you can only use record syntax when a) you have the c-tor, or b) when you have a value of the type. If you have neither and just want to create the value, then you need to use regular function call syntax.

Comment: I basically want to use a smart constructor, while using record syntax. Using functions with 13 `->` in them isn't fun at all.

Comment: One of the invariants is basically `<` on `Int` so enumerating the combinations as types is not feasible.

Comment: not sure if I get the question still but what about providing a empty/default value with valid entries and then provide functions that change certain values in a fashion that keeps the data valid? Or splitting the data into smaller subsets?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. What do you mean by using record syntax ? could you add an example of how you would the final code to look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to post my first comment in a bit more elaborated way, and maybe you'll find this good enough.

First, let's assume your data looks more or less like this:

```
data MyBigData = MyBigData {
   a :: ...
   b :: ...
   ...
   z :: ...
}
```

Indeed, when replaced with smart constructor, you can't do much about that problem.

However, assuming your library functions look more or less like this:

```
libFun :: MyBigData -> Result
```

I propose the following solution. Create a wrapping type:

```
newtype ValidData = ValidData MyBigData
```

Don't export its constructor. Change your functions to:

```
libFun :: ValidData -> Result
libFun (ValidData d) = ...
```

And put the validation logic in a function:

```
validate :: MyBigData -> Maybe ValidData
```

Now when calling `validate` you can use record syntax, but you won't be able to use this data in any function that actually expects it in coherent state if you don't validate it first.

```
input = validate $ MyBigData { ... }
case input of:
    Just d -> libFun d
    Nothing -> ...
```

Of course in this case `validate` could also return `Either` or perhaps act monadically if you need that.

Comment: On top of that, if you have more than one such data type, it could perhaps be a nice place for `DataFamilies`. Create a generic `newtype Valid a = Valid a` and a `class Validable` with `origType :: a`, `validType :: Valid a`, and `validate :: a -> Valid a`. Not sure if that would work or what it would buy, but perhaps work exploring.

Comment: How can you make your module _extensible_, i.e. allow users of your module to use  the constructor `ValidData` in a pattern (like in the definition of `libFun`) if you don't export it? Now, `ghc` complains: `Not in scope: data constructor ‘ValidData’`

Comment: @HansLub The definition of `libFun` specifically meant this is a library function that operates on valid data. However, in that case you could also export an extraction function, like the other answer does, because `ValidData -> MyBigData` is always safe.

Comment: @Bartek_Banachewicz: ... but you wouldn't be able to use your extraction function directly  in patterns; as you can using `viewPatterns`, .e.g. when writing a function that operates on `[ValidData]`

Comment: If you are already going to write a validation function it might be a good idea to go for `Either String MyBigData` or `Either [String] MyBigData` to include the first or all error messages. See maybe digestive-functors for some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I would use  Bartek Banachewicz suggestion to use an auxiliary data type `Blueprint` with an open and unvalidated constructor, and `ActualData` smart constructor `fromBluePrint :: Blueprint -> ActualData`, in combination with a trivial function

```
 section :: ActualData -> Blueprint
```

that just 'throws away'  the validation (meaning that `fromBlueprint . section` is the identity on `ActualData` - *section* is [another name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) for *right inverse*)

Now, you can use [viewPatterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) and write code like

```
 x :: ActualData
 x = fromBlueprint $ Blueprint {a=1, b="baz",...}

 f :: ActualData -> Int
 f (section -> Blueprint{a=x}) = 2*x
```

using record syntax in constructing values of type `ActualData` and in patterns when defining functions on `ActualData` (or on more complicated types like `[ActualData]`, as views can be nested)

Comment: See also: [Can constraints be enforced on public data types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893351/can-constraints-be-enforced-on-public-data-types/23893832#23893832)